# Multiple Conditions in array Php

Tags: php, arrays

I have following array with start time and end time (both saved in database)

```
$cars=array("09:00","09:30","10:00","10:30","11:00","11:30","12:00","12:30");
```

and i want to show booked time (saved in database) and availiable time, I tried with following code

```
$start = "09:30";
$end = "10:30";
$availability = array_combine($cars, array_map(function ($v) use ($start, $end) { 
    return (strtotime($v) < strtotime($start) || strtotime($v) > strtotime($end)) ? 'available' : 'booked'; }, 
    $cars));
```

showing result

```
Array
(
    [09:00] => available
    [09:30] => booked
    [10:00] => booked
    [10:30] => booked
    [11:00] => available
    [11:30] => available
    [12:00] => available
    [12:30] => available
)
```

but i have multiple start time and end time(dynamically) so how can i get result (like above) ?

Comment: Your question is Unclear because you failed to explain how your _multiple start time and end time_ data is fed to the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$times = array("09:00","09:30","10:00","10:30","11:00","11:30","12:00","12:30");
$availability = array_fill_keys($times, 'available');

function book(&$availability, $start, $end)
{
    foreach($availability as $k => $v)
        if(strtotime($k) >= strtotime($start) && strtotime($k) <= strtotime($end))
            $availability[$k] = 'booked';

}

book($availability, '09:30', '10:30');
book($availability, '11:30', '12:00');

print_r($availability);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [09:00] => available
    [09:30] => booked
    [10:00] => booked
    [10:30] => booked
    [11:00] => available
    [11:30] => booked
    [12:00] => booked
    [12:30] => available
)
```

Comment: Please add explanation.

Comment: @mickmackusa I don't think there is much to explain here, but by all means edit away.

Comment: You and I know how modifying by reference works, but that is not common knowledge for all developers.  You know that all answers should include explanation, this is not your first day here.  I don't clean up other people's code-only answers.  This teaches other volunteers to be lazy.

Comment: @mickmackusa I am not going to spell out minutiae.  The code, input sample and output is explanatory enough here IMHO.

Comment: I am sorry to hear your stance, because it will only encourage other volunteers to post code only answers.  Code-only answer = 25 points. 
 Stackoverflow only weakens as a result.  You could have added an explanation in the time wasted commenting.

Comment: @mickmackusa likewise, you could have just edited it.

Comment: Edge cases are more important here.  If for example someone tries to book from 09:01 to 09:28, this will not book out the slot, because of the conditional checks.

Comment: I am not a janitor.  That work only perpetuates laziness in other volunteers.